# change image gallery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how i can to make these changes in below code?

- show thumbnail image title for `<div id="main">` when we click, thumb image.
- show thumbnail image title below of `<div id="main">`
- set URL thumbnail image for "blank.gif" ( i mean when we click thumb image, `<div id="main">` get URL of that thumb image, also. i want make this change for use full-screen of any image)

code here:

```
<div id="main">
    <p><img src="blank.gif" /></p>
</div>

$(".productthumbs img").click(function() {
    // calclulate large image's URL based on the thumbnail URL (flickr specific)
    var url = $(this).attr("src");
    // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semitransparent
    var wrap = $("#main").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);
    // the large image from flickr
    var img = new Image();
    // call this function after it's loaded
    img.onload = function() {
        // make wrapper fully visible
        wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);
        // change the image
        wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);
    };
    // begin loading the image from flickr
    img.src = url;
// when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
}).filter(":first").click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my answer, put it here for anyone have same asking...

```
<div id="main">
    <p><img src="blank.gif" /></p>

    <div id="title">
       <a href="about:blank"><h5>...</h5> </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add these lines :

```
wrap.find('h5').html(title);
wrap.find("a").eq(1).attr("href", url);
```

after :

```
    wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);
```

Good luck.